# Could not import cufflinks

Tags: python, python-3.6

### Problem

I am trying to install both *plotly* and *cufflinks*. However I had a problem.

The installation of both *plotly* and *cufflinks* were successful. Although, I can't import cufflinks.

Below is a picture of the problem. It seems to be a dependency error:

[image: *Error in Jupyter Notebook*]

I tried manually downloading and installing "talib" but I keep getting failures. (Shown below).

```
talib\common.c(240): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ta_libc.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Any Ideas? I tried re-installing both modules and Anaconda. Nothing So far.

### Other infos:

1. Cufflinks version: 0.11.0
2. Plotly version: 2.0.10
3. Anaconda version: 3-4.4.0 (But I don't think it have anything to do with it)
4. Python version: 3.6.1

Comment: Have you tried cloning the github distribution into your local repo and running `python setup.py install`?

Comment: Yes. Same problem

Comment: You possibly are installing for the wrong Python version. Check to see if you have multiple versions on your comp and install it for the right one.

Comment: I uninstalled every version of python and reinstalled only the Anaconda distribution version. Still no results. I beleive I have ONLY python 3.6 from anaconda. But just to be sure, how can I rapidly check for the versions?

Comment: you can open an interpreter, type: import sys; sys.version

Comment: 3.6.1 Anaconda 64-bits. And I found this https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib#troubleshooting

Comment: Did it work? If it did, consider writing a small answer with your quick fix and marking it to help future readers. :)

Comment: Hum... Some what yes. I will write a small answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this link: [github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib#troubleshooting](http://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib#troubleshooting)

### Troubleshooting

Sometimes installation will produce build errors like this:

```
func.c:256:28: fatal error: ta-lib/ta_libc.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

This typically means that it can't find the underlying TA-Lib library, a dependency which needs to be installed. On Windows, this could be caused by installing the 32-bit binary distribution of the underlying TA-Lib library, but trying to use it with 64-bit Python.

### Windows

Download ta-lib-0.4.0-msvc.zip and unzip to C:\ta-lib

This is a 32-bit release. If you want to use 64-bit Python, you will need to build a 64-bit version of the library.

### My Fix

So, for windows, we need a 64-bit version of the library? Luckly I found a lot of modules built for 32 and 64 bits python:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

search for "ta-lib" and click on the module you need (In my case cp36 64 bits).

Then, open the command prompt.

Change to where you downloaded the file: `cd path/to/file`

Type: `pip install NameOfFile` (in my case `pip install TA_Lib‑0.4.10‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` )

Now the 64-bits Ta-Lib module should be installed in your machine. I tested the previous line of codes and it worked!

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

try installing this version of cufflinks, it eliminated the error for me.

pip install cufflinks==0.8.2

Answer (score 1):

I have now removed all dependencies on talib. All studies are pure python based now and you should not face any of this errors.